# regex for string contains 1 characted

Tags: php, regex

i need help writing a simple regular expresion.

I have string like:

```
13.03.2014 12:07:00;13.03.2014 00:00:00;Refund;4446633804;RUB;0.01;test 374383457;9645282;13.03.2014 12:05:31;1122;1122;88282;
```

I need to check that every column (`;`) contains at least 1 characted (or just not empty).

How i can do that?

Comment: This doesn’t need regex; an “empty column” exists when there are two consecutive semicolons, or the first character of the line is one – for both of which you can test using simple string functions.

Comment: Have you tried anyting or are you just coming here for others to do your job?

Comment: where is your current code failing?

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (! preg_match("^\s*;|;\s*;", $input)) {
         echo "No empty columns!"
    }
```

This simply verifies that the `$input` does not start with a semi-colon, and doesn't have two successive semicolons (possibly separated by spaces) either.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think something like this?

```
^([^;]+;)*$
```

//nonzero non semicolon characters and one semicolon repeating from the beginning to the end?

It matches also empty and requires semicolon on the end.
Is that what you want?

Comment: This would match `foo;  ;bar;`, and `[;]` is the same as `;`: you don't need the character range. Also it would break if there are trailing whitespaces at the end of the string

Comment: whitespace is not allowed content of the column?

Comment: No idea (OP isn't very responsive), I just thought this should be made clear.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use the PHP explode function to convert the string into an array. Then you can loop through the array and check each value using a simple regular expression.

```
$cols = explode(";", $myrecord);
$matched = preg_match('/.+/',$cols[0]);
```

If the element contains at least one character, $matched will be assigned a value of 1.

If you need to perform the same test on every element, then put loop through array.

Comment: If you're not checking on blanks characters (whitespaces, tabs, etc) regex seem like an overkill to me... Why not just check `$cols[0]`'s length?

Answer (score 0):

just `;;` will do it. check if this is present, which means your one column is empty

Comment: You can just check for `;;`, you don't need the `+`.

Comment: Except if the empty column is the first one. But I agree with you, after this small update this should be the way to it.

Answer (score -2):

Check out this regex

```
^\(\S+\)$
```

Comment: That's a cool regex indeed. What does it have to do with the subject?

Comment: how does this regex even come in the picture ?